# jQuery select paragraphs with minimum contained text character count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to target paragraphs with a minimum of 500 character. Then use them as a selector to insert a `div.in-between` every 3 of those paragraphs that meet this criteria.

I know we can do page and individual paragraph text character count using:

Text character count: `$('div.container').text().replace(/[^A-Z]/gi,'').length;`

Paragraph count: `$('div.container p').text().split(' ').length;`

**How do I accomplish this using jQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter to target elements with a minimum of 500 characters.
The `\W` regex removes anything that does not match  a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore.

Once the collection is filtered you can use `$.grep` to get every third element and insert a div after each of those elements.

```
var paragraphs = $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\W/g, '').length > 500;
});

var nth3 = $.grep(paragraphs, function(_, index) {
    return (index + 1) % 3 === 0;
})

$(nth3).after('<div class="in-between"></div>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DjAuL/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'after'`.

Comment: @Steve - Yep, forgot to wrap the last variable, $.grep returns an array.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks, if you throw readabilty out the window, you could even just wrap them all into one, just for fun -> http://jsfiddle.net/DjAuL/1/